# Magento 2: Zendframework dependency not installed

Tags: magento2.2, composer

We're running Magento2 v2.2.10. And we're deploying the repo using Capistrano but it fails during bin/magento tasks.

`An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig).`

The issue and simply appears to be that it is missing the `Zendframework` (the folder and its sub-packages do not exist in vendor).

We've tried to include it in our composer.json manually but without luck. Copying the `Zendframework` folder from a backup into /vendor solves the issue. If we manually run `composer update/install` in the release folder it works (after deleting the vendor folder). We've tried to play around with composer flags but it didn't care.

What the hell is going on? >=(

==

The composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.10",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.10",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "mollie/magento2": "^1.9",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites": "^1.5",
        "sendcloud/sendcloud": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.4.5",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, delete everything. Cache and vendor folder included and things might turn out ok again.